# Sql query with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select Query in employee table. I need to make sure that column `value(empaddress)` always pass an empty value in select query:

```
SELECT 
    empname,
    empaddress,
    empDeptid  
FROM 
    empiD=3
```

I know that empaddress can contain any value like Null or data. But in the result set it should always be blank

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    empname,
    "" as empaddress,
    empDeptid   
FROM 
   empiD=3
```

Unless I am missing something here that would return a blank string in place of the empaddress

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    empname,
    null as empaddress,
    empDeptid   
FROM 
    empiD=3;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I did not think of just doing null like that. Might be more performant too

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT empname, Isnull(empaddress,'')empaddress, empDeptid FROM empiD=3
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `ISNULL` function with '' and it will appear blank:

```
SELECT 
    empname,
    ISNULL(empaddress,'') AS EmpAddress,
    empDeptid  
FROM 
    empiD=3
```